# how to add wrong predicted data with other data segment for next prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have 50 data in csv, i want to do evaluation in this way,

Breaking data into 5 segment, this is 1-10, 11-20, 21-30, 31-40,  41-50

FOR EXAMPLE:
select 10 data for training

```
train_data = X[:10]
y_train = y[:10]
```

select next 10 data for testing

```
test_data = X[11:20]
y_test = y[11:20]
```

now I'm applying decision tree first base leaner

```
dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier()
dtc.fit(train_data, y_train)
test_preds = dtc.predict(test_data)
test_accuracy = accuracy_score(test_preds, y_test)
```

now I'm identifying:

```
wrongly_predicted_records = test_data[test_preds != y_test]
```

Again select the records 21 to 30 for training the second base learner.

```
train_data_1 = X[21:30]
y_train_1 = y[21:30]
```

Then I combine the records 31 to 40 and the wrongly predicted records from the first base learner for evaluation of the second base learner.

```
test_data_1 = X[31:40]._append(wrongly_predicted_records)
y_test_1 = y[31:40]
```

The second base leaner

```
lr = LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(train_data_1, y_train_1)
```

Here I evaluate the logistic regression classifier on the second evaluation data but i get value error.

```
test_preds_1 = lr.predict(test_data_1)
test_accuracy_1 = accuracy_score(test_preds_1, y_test_1)

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [127, 99]
```

The shape are [127,] and [99,] help me please

note the X = [all data in csv encoded except class column]
the y = [only class column encoded]
It means 0 to 1 values

Answer (score 0):

You should update new code to select 10 data. Your current code only select 9

```
test_data = X[10:20]
y_test = y[10:20]

train_data_1 = X[20:30]
y_train_1 = y[20:30]
```

Comment: This is not a solution but it is true idea I need to solve the error since it seem that the number of the number of dataset are not equals how to solve it